# 3 column with float isn't working properly

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

I try to do a responsive email templating using antwork template. I've problem of adding the 4th column, as you can see the broken design here : http://jsfiddle.net/cS8Tp/embedded/result/

```
<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:13px; line-height: 20px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
```

Comment: Use % instead of px for responsive template by pixel your restricting it to be specific size

Comment: `%` is only *required* if you want fluid - it is not technically required for responsive, but helps bridge the gaps between different views. By using `px` with media queries, your layout would just pop between states, which may be desired in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use DIV instead of table. apply width in %

Answer (score 1):

The reason your 4-col is not working is because the widths of all 4 tables add up to more than the 600px width you have allocated in the master table. Change the width of the 4 tables to 129px and it will work. 600 divided by 4 is 150. You have 20px of padding in each, leaving 130px. Sometimes floating tables with the exact width breaks, which is why 129px is the width your cells should be set to.